# PayPal Login via PHP cURL, Website Changed

Tags: php, curl, paypal

I was using cURL to connect to a PayPal account and get some informations!
but it seems that the web site won't let me connect using cURL! that error has begin from yesterday!

I've tried to connect to my account with two steps, one for login, and the second for Captcha! but it seems not working too!

when submitting my login details, the response is the same as the login page with no changes.

> **captcha**=wSne7657
>
> **_csrf**=PqvBTbDak4NhcFF1MgH1dYD1w2c+l2abHtsPg=
>
> continue=Continue

my script will capture the **_csrf** , and the Captcha image, so I can write the **captcha** Code! but it's still not working!

Can any one help me with a new curl function to connect to my PayPal account in PHP?

***after submitting the captcha and _csrf code i just get this header and content page encrypted!!***

> I got a 403 forbidden header!!

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Server: Apache
X-Recruiting: If you are reading this, maybe you should be working at PayPal instead! Check out https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/paypal-jobs
Paypal-Debug-Id: 28f94fc64d609
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Security-Policy: 0 [object Object]; 1 block-all-mixed-content; 2 reflected-xss block;
ETag: W/"947-FrkxgU3rnbas1vjZ+q5aPw"
HTTP_X_PP_AZ_LOCATOR: dcg11.slc
Paypal-Debug-Id: 28f94fc64d609
Content-Encoding: gzip
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
DC: slc-b-origin-www-2.paypal.com
Content-Length: 1102
X-EdgeConnect-MidMile-RTT: 173
X-EdgeConnect-Origin-MEX-Latency: 173
Date: Fri, 05 Aug 2016 14:13:50 GMT
Connection: close
Set-Cookie: LANG=en_US%3BUS; Domain=.paypal.com; Path=/; Expires=Fri, 05 Aug 2016 22:59:46 GMT; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: tsrce=authchallengenodeweb; Domain=.paypal.com; Path=/; Expires=Sat, 06 Aug 2016 14:13:50 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure
Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=name%3DLIVE6.WEB.1%26silo_version%3D880%26app%3Dauthchallengenodeweb%26TIME%3D513778775%26HTTP_X_PP_AZ_LOCATOR%3Ddcg11.slc; Expires=Fri, 05 Aug 2016 14:43:50 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
Set-Cookie: AKDC=slc-b-origin-www-2.paypal.com; expires=Fri, 05-Aug-2016 14:43:50 GMT; path=/; secure
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000

��V[S�8�+��/�I|K��N�M   �6
۝�"ˎ�,  IN�}��P���>�̓F�����N�,����u*��8�R�psI�r�-��8J�'�$QDK�5  }�Jsv˝������2�  �*7���  QJ(f� �*u����~�4J�Kd��y�q�AL�:~}Zi+a�הv�KC�tI��q�z�y'�[.�{�$bb:'��=,J@h�D�Q3c��z�� -�3zc�ȨZ�#%S��!�/Y���V_VSF1l)%C�h�o�e/��q%*��1�T����OZRh�6���(h��VⲂ�ԅ���ňᴕ�� �Q�E~�U���7�����8׮N1u1�iLӸ� �g�à�&I<
p�[A��$.���(�F+�rx\y+��f�[�Ό�+/S�(���n  ưbp0u�vRk;�2��;+[Na�+�rYf+ml�u�2����͵ge&x#�I9�k�N�ď�hon+GW:����9
`An�.������{v7�z�Xe���&�
�-�w)z�mma�K�3d��Zg�9۶u/e�[��������y��b�(���`�#MƊm5��Q���浛S/�ߌ`?$q���0KP�GQ�nzu���
�@
ԏ��z����G��)%ZT��\pE��;����>�O�!υM;����zU�wv�4���lwC���z�̄6����h�o�4r��g    ��o�Nr#.����qHh�K�+rs��W����?��|������F���ǃ>IlP�(�d;�zG˰
����:�����w�hѺ�b���u�U`�����Uk��?x?*;'}v'��fbx������Q��k?�Ǘ۱����f�S?KHl�k����Ʊmcg�V0^xŘ�
o/5�z�ђ�    N��CTI9�/ʂ��
```

so after that, I tried to disable the javascript on my browser to test if the main website still accept logins without javascript, I saw that the problem is that PayPal website doesn't accept login without javascript! so I must find a way to connect using cURL!

my php code is:

```
<?php
function curl($url = '', $var = '', $header = false, $nobody = false)
{

    $xCookies = "cookies.txt";  
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, $nobody);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Maxthon/3.0 Safari/533.9');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://www.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_run-check-cookie-submit&redirectCmd=_login-submit');
    if ($var) {
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $var);
    }
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $xCookies);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $xCookies);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    // curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); /*****/
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $result;
}
        $var = 'login_cmd=&login_params=&login_email='.rawurlencode($user) .'&login_password='.rawurlencode($pass) .'&target_page=0&submit.x=Log+In&form_charset=UTF-8&browser_name=Firefox&browser_version=17&browser_version_full=17.0&operating_system=Windows';
        $page = curl("https://www.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_run-check-cookie-submit&redirectCmd=_login-submit", $var);
//[.....]
?>
```

Comment: @Jonasw, I've edited the post, please check the code

Comment: Isn't that paypal is trying to prohibit by all means such connections ?

Comment: "403 Forbidden" says it all. Theres a good reason for it: to prevent phishing. Use the paypal api (?) instead.

Comment: I can't use the API, because I need to enter the account of the client to get his informations like address, phone, ..etc these features doesn't work via API, only cURL!